# Is nvidia-xrun available only for Arch? How do I install it?

Tags: nvidia, software-installation, nvidia-optimus

I recently found [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/6ftq10/the_ultimate_guide_to_setting_up_nvidia_optimus/) on Reddit. And there I found out about [nvidia-xrun](https://github.com/Witko/nvidia-xrun). I tried to google how to use it with Ubuntu but didn't find anything I could make a use of. Is it possible to use it with Ubuntu at all? If yes, how to install it from Aur?

Comment: I dont think you can install aur packages on ubuntu, unless you decide to rewrite `makepkg` to run on your system, and rewrite the `PKGBUILD`. I have been wrong before though

Comment: There's nothing much to install. In the README you'll see a bunch of files and directories listed ("/usr/bin/nvidia-xrun - the executable script

/etc/X11/nvidia-xorg.conf -...") Just copy the files from the repo to the appropriate locations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)